# How to prevent "MongoError: Transaction 1 has been committed."?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

### Problem

Using MongoDB 4.2, I'm trying to execute 50,000 transactions (50,000 array mutations). Like 90 % are successful but for the rest I get:

> MongoError: Transaction 1 has been committed.

Unfortunately, I don't even understand the error message!

### Approach

One Reddit user suggested to upgrade to 4.2 to overcome the 16 MB oplog limitation. But that didn't help.

### Code

I think it doesn't matter here but for the sake of completeness my Node.js code:

```
const rowCollection = client.db('docemur').collection('row')
session.startTransaction()

// Reorder rows according to columns
await rowCollection
  .find({ table: table._id }, { session })
  .forEach(async row => {
    // Reorder the row array
    row.row = sortBy(row.row, unsorted => {
      return findIndex(columns, sorted => unsorted.column === sorted.identifier)
    })

    // Update the now ordered row
    await rowCollection
      .updateOne(
        { _id: row._id },
        { $set: { row: row.row } },
        { session }
      )
  })

await session.commitTransaction()
session.endSession()
```

Comment: You need to use [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#db.collection.updateMany) when updating this many documents.

Comment: @DanStarns this is actually a very great idea. It will be faster and likely solve my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: cool stuff! i updated the answer !

Comment: I still have to test it ;) Will report back soon.

Comment: @Julian Were you able convert the above code to use bulkWrite?? By any chance do you have the code. I am also getting the same error and tried bulkWrite but still getting the same error

Comment: My Issue is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65426546/transaction-1-has-been-committed-in-mongodb. Any assistance is much appreciated

Comment: I didn't get it to work. I talked even with the MongoDB support and they suggested just work arounds. Maybe it changed already.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-updateonemany) when updating this many documents.